# MYSQL show 0 even if results do not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql database with 2 tables:

```
countries
results
```

- Countries is just and `id` and a `country name`.
- Results is a `country_id`, a `value` and a `date`.
- Not all countries have results on each date.

How can I create a query that lists all countries with their specific result, but still list them and shows 0 if there is no result on the results table?

Comment: Or just combine it into one table, with nulls for the countries that have no value or date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN between the two tables

```
select c.id, c.name, IFNULL(r.value, 0) value, r.date
from countries c
LEFT JOIN results r on r.country_id = c.id
```

To show 0 (for the `value` column) if there is no result, use [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

Comment: cool, thanks for that. 
how about if i do not want to list some of the countries?

Comment: You put a where clause at the end, as the 4th line.

Comment: Hi, i tried this code 
---- 
SELECT r.statistic, r.type, c.id, c.name, IFNULL(r.value, 0) value, r.date_from 
FROM dt_countries c LEFT JOIN results r on r.country = c.id 
ORDER BY statistic, type, name  ----

but some of the "statistics" values do not get matched with all the contries. i didnt mention there was 3 more fields on the results table, not sure if that makes a diff.

Comment: @Jon Please elaborate by editing question and putting some sample data rows and expected output for that data.

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for is called `LEFT JOIN`. take a look at [this page](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php) or ask google for an easy example. for more information, take a look at the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

Answer (score 0):

With following query you will fetch all countries with assigned results to them.

```
   SELECT *
     FROM countries AS c
LEFT JOIN results AS r
       ON r.country_id = c.id
```

If there are no values assigned to some countries, there will be `null` values and according to them you will know you should show `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take into account all the dates that are stored in the `results` table and to list all the countries for all those dates, replacing `results.value` with `0` accordingly, then you might probably need to do something like this:

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  IFNULL(r.value, 0) AS value,
  r.date
FROM countries c
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM results) d
  LEFT JOIN results r ON c.id = r.country_id AND d.date = r.date
```